# Local HTML validation tool for Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, validation

I am after a HTML validation tool for Firefox to run locally on my development machine.

I have tried **Total Validator**.  But it’s crazy, it keeps telling me to upgrade, I have done that several times.

I am using the **Web Developer** extension. The local CSS validation works fine, but the local HTML validation hangs.

Can someone recommend another one?

Comment: don't forget that FireFox has a version designed specifically for development https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Developer_Edition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have [HTML Validator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/html-validator/) installed. It does a pretty good job, a simple icon in the toolbar will tell you when something is off:

[image]

If you click the icon you get the source code with a list of errors:

[image]

I use it to validate pages locally before uploading them.

Comment: I just installed it, no drama , no fuss. It works.

Comment: I'm using this for years (Jan beat me with his answer, else I had recommended it). So: thumbs up for this!

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to invest some time and disk space the **definitive** validator is the [W3C online validator](https://validator.w3.org).

You can however also download a snapshot of the validator and run it yourself offline, you will need an instance of Apache Web server, Perl, some Perl libraries and the validator itself.

This [guide](https://validator.w3.org/docs/install_win.html) explains how to install and run your own validator instance on Windows.  For other platforms the [installation guide](https://validator.w3.org/docs/install.html) gives details.

*All the above is available Free, Gratis and Open Source - you are encouraged to feed back any bugs you spot and you are obliged by the GPL licence to give back any bug fixes and/or enhancements that you might make.*

As an example I ran this page through the W3C validator and it came up with the following report:

[image]