# What development environment or software can I use to debug HTML5?

Tags: html

I am a C# [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) programmer.

Recently I started learning MVC with [DevExtreme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevExpress#Product_list) and started working through [a tutorial](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Tutorial/UI_Widgets/Add_Widget_to_MVC_Project/?version=15_1).

I found the tutorial project would build in [Visual Studio 2013](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2013), but that the application would not work correctly (a button would not appear). This puzzled me for some time until I realized that the incorrect references inside the .cshtml file were not causing the build to break as they would in a Windows Forms project.

What software or development environment is there to assist with debugging HTML code?

Comment: See also http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21279/local-html-validation-tool-for-firefox and look for similar plugins for whichever browser you use. Also, press F12 in most browsers for developer tools and don't forget that FireFox has a version designed specifically for development https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Developer_Edition

Answer (score 1):

[Amaya](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/) by the [W3C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium) is, unsurprisingly, the most standards compliant IDE that there is it.

[image]

I have used it for years for pure HTML, although I tend use other IDEs when mixing HTML with code such as PHP, AngularJs or NodeJs. Alas, I have no experience of C#.

If you doubt the HTML produced by your C#, then run it through [the official validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: thanks @Mawg. Can Amaya detect if a reference path in the head section is not correct?  Visual Studo +Resharper can visually highlight that the path is incorrect, but the project will still build without error - which surprised me since a bad reference will cause an error in a WinForms build.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick google search Aptana is a good open source editor. It is free. And it looks like a pretty good ide. Another one is notepad++ it color codes your code but does not provide debugging info I wonder why visual studio does not work. I would try reinstalling it because visual studio has the best ide

Comment: Welcome aboard and thanks for trying to help. However, `a quick google search` is not really an acceptable answer. We presume that the OP is capable of googling for himself. Ideally, we like answers from someone who has experience of the tool which they are recommending and who explain how it will help the OP attain his stated goals. Please read [answer]. But, again, welcome aboard, thanks for trying to help and I hope that we will see more of you around.