# Looking for a HTML and CSS validator tool, preferably for the whole website

Tags: html, css, validation

There is this [Post here on a tool for Firefox](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21279/local-html-validation-tool-for-firefox) which is 8 years old.

I am using a browser version of a Validator on Chrome which only does HTML and only does one page.

I am looking for something that could do the whole web site, either by using the sitemap or another file where I can list the pages.  It can do it on my PC with Xampp or on the live version of my website.  I don't mind paying up to about $100.

Answer (score 1):

**W3C Markup Validation Service:** This is a well-known and widely used tool for validating HTML markup. It's available as a web service, and you can also download the source code and host it on your local environment. It can validate individual pages or entire websites by submitting a sitemap or list of URLs.

Visit https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

These days you likely want something like [html-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-validator) for a specific programming language, in this case Javascript, configured to scan output HTML/CSS files and hooked into CI for automated validation.

Unless of course there's some user input that can result in different HTML which would normally not be checked. In that case you can generate special test output just for tests and cover all the cases that need to be covered. Might not work for your website depending on what it is and what exactly you need to verify, but I'm mentioning it as the most optimal possibility for lots of more basic sites.